# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandStr) is not working on Mac OS X 10.12(Sierra)

Tags: java, macos, runtime.exec

I am trying to create a directory and with created directory doing mount operation of selected network drive. The code is working on other OS X version like OS X Lion or Caption but not working on OS X 10.12(Sierra)
Please suggest how this code will work.

```
proc=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/mkdir","/Volumes/Library"+count});  
int exitCode = proc.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exit code : "+exitCode);
```

and then mounting the drive

```
String[] commandArr = new String[]{"/sbin/mount","-t","smbfs","//username:password@IP-Of-System/library"," /Volumes/Library"+count};
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArr);
```

This command is running with terminal but not executing using Runtime.getRuntime().exec().

Comment: check if user who initiated java program has permission for the command to execute. ?

Comment: I run this on terminal it shows Operation not permitted then I tried these command using "sudo" then it runs on terminal but not executing with java code using sudo as well.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: presumably sudo requires entry of a password. Your java application cannot automatically put in the password

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is that getRuntime().exec does not give you a full shell.
You can't assume that you can just do anything with it that you can do from a shell (the "command line").

You can try ProcessBuilder.start() (recommended in the Runtime.exec documentation), but that likely won't help either.

To make this work, you can create a shell script that does what you want, and then use Runtime.exec or ProcessBuilder.start to execute the script, passing the appropriate parameters to it.

Comment: I tried this using shell script as well but it is not running, actually I fin on Mac-OSX Sierra 10.12 version that Not only maker and  mount command is not running  whether I am using  Runtime.exe() or ProcessBuilder. By using process build only other application being executed.